# Filament SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

When I create a new row in the table 'partidos' I get this message:

> 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '

That is ok, I know it is a duplicate entry, but I get an error page from Laravel. My question is, how I can get an alert or similar instead of that error page?

I tried to use laravel validation rules, but I don't know how to use them with Filament

[image]

Thanks

Comment: you can use unique validation rule in your controller like  'email' => 'unique:users,email_address',  //here users is table name and email_address is column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`QueryException`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.html) is being thrown due to the duplicate key violation in your `partidos` table.

You could encapsulate your statement(s) in a `try/catch` block to catch and handle the exception however you see fit. For example:

```
try {
    // perform your database action here
} catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){ 
    // $ex->getMessage(); will provide a string representation of the error
    // from here you can handle the exception and return a response
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic), specifically the [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique) rule to validate any values that must be unique in the database table are in fact unique.

```
public function action(Request $request)
{
    // if validation fails, laravel will redirect back to the page with errors
    $request->validate([
        'field' => ['required', 'unique:partidos'],
    ]);
}
```